# how to hide "next" barbutton when no cell is checked?

Tags: ios, xcode, checkbox, tableview

how can i hide the 'next'barbuttonitem when no cell is checked. but when i check min 1 cell, the next button should be available.

here is my didselectedrow:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    StandortCell *cell = (StandortCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Standort *standort=[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Ausgewaehlte Standort %@",standort.ort);

    if (cell.checkButton.hidden==YES){
        cell.checkButton.hidden=NO;
        UIBarButtonItem *myWeiter = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Weiter" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextPressed:)];
        UIBarButtonItem *myMapButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Karte" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mapPressed:)]; 

        NSArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myWeiter,myMapButton,nil];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = myButtonArray;
    }else {
        cell.checkButton.hidden=YES;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        UIBarButtonItem *myMapButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Karte" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mapPressed:)]; 

        NSArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myMapButton,nil];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = myButtonArray;
    }    

    if ([[standort valueForKey:@"ortcheck"] boolValue]) {
        [standort setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"ortcheck"];

    } else {

        [standort setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"ortcheck"];

    }


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }




}
```

when i try my code the nextbutton disappears but when i select more than one cell and deselect one, the nextbutton disappears. it should disappear when no cell is selected

Answer (score 0):

When the view is built add the buttons:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *myWeiter = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Weiter" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextPressed:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *myMapButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Karte" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(mapPressed:)]; 

    NSArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myWeiter,myMapButton,nil];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = myButtonArray;
}
```

When a row gets selected the button should always be visible (as there is at least 1 selected):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
```

when a row gets deselected this will get called and if there are no selected rows disable the rightbarbutton:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] == nil) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i select a few cells an deselect them again, the button didn't hide again :(

Comment: that is because this method will only be called when a row gets selected. Use the method im adding now.

Comment: i think you don't understand my question. when the view is open,  the next button is hidden, after i tapped min 1 cells it shows me a checkmark and the next button is visible. but when i deselect all the selected cells, the checkmark disappears but the next button is still visible

Comment: Hmmm could you try this? it will not remove the buttons, but it will make the buttons unusable and grayed out.

Comment: you could also just remove the button as you did in your code example and rebuild them when you need them again.

Comment: i tried it, but i think there is a problem with your diddeselectrow, because when i select the views and deselect it, nothing happens.

Comment: have you tried changing the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;` to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil;`? that should do the trick if im not mistaken.. You should also put the piece of code thats inside the viewDidLoad and put it into the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: i tried your new solution too, but the button didn't disappear :S

Comment: Do you NEED 2 buttons or could you have only 1 button or a segmented control or something? because i believe the problem lies in the usage of the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` in stead of `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` (multiple vs single button)

Comment: i tried it with just one button, but its still the same problem. when i click in a cell twice then the function didDeselectRowIndePath should be start but it isn't. really strange

Comment: Ah but that might be a problem with the delegate connection from your UITableView to your class. rightclick the UITableView in the interface builder to see if it has a delegate and sourcedelegate connected to it.

Comment: That is odd, so you mean to say that neither of these methods are called at all? Can you place an NSLog like `NSLog(@"didSelect");` in both of the methods at the top (so not within an if statement)? Thats to check if the methods get called or not.